# How can I cause a Memory Error in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, testing, memory-management, out-of-memory

I'm working on a system that has about 128KB of RAM, one of my scripts occasionally causes a ERRNO 12 Cannot Allocate Memory error.

I have a few solutions I want to test.

But how can I replicate the problem when it seemingly happens randomly once a day?

Any bad scripts that will cause ERRNO 12 Cannot Allocate Memory error?

Most posts are trying to solve Memory errors, I want to cause one to test the robustness of my code.

Comment: Mmmm somthing like `[None]*1000000000`? You are using micropython, I'm assuming?

Comment: Have you tried reading a large enough text file into a String variable?

Comment: python 2.7 on an OpenWRT Embedded Device

Comment: While it is easy to create a MemoryError, I don't see how doing so will assist you fixing your problem. Often (not always) a MemoryError can leave the application in an undesired and undefined state that might cause problems later. That makes this kind of error hard to recover from.

Comment: Do you want to run out of memory completely or do you want to get a `MemoryError`? In the first case your system may just completely crash and you will not be able to catch it. The only way I can get a `MemoryError` thrown and catch it is by using the 32-bit version of python which uses at most 4GB of ram.

Comment: Essentially my embedded device has a Errno 12 Cannot Allocate Memory error towards the end of the day, approximately 10pm. Then the system reboots at midnight and we're all good till roughly 10pm again

Comment: I've inserted a manual garbage collection using gc.collect() that seems to have helped a bit

Comment: But I need to make sure we're not gonna randomly crash

Comment: I could easily just reboot the system when this error happens but it's not a very elegant solution

Answer (score 3):

If you want to force Python to run out of memory, this should make it happen very quickly regardless of how much memory is available:

```
x = [None]
while True:
    x += x
```

This will double the length of `x` on every iteration until it fails.